# Output R-squared using Linear Regression on subsets of data

Tags: r, linear-regression, tidyverse

I have a dataset with `lag`, `psit`, and `var` as variables.

```
set.seed(560)
df<-data.frame(lag= rep(1:40, each=228), psit= rep(rnorm(228, 20, 
10)),var=rnorm(9120, 50, 10))
```

For each subset of `lag` I would like to run a linear regression where psit is predicted by var `lm(psit~var, df)`. I would like to output the R-squared value, the F-statistic and the p-value for the model into a datatframe.

```
output<-data.frame(lag= rep(1:40, each=1), rsqrd= rep(rnorm(40, .5, 
0.01)),fstat=rnorm(40,5, 0.05), pvalue=rnorm(40,0.01, 0.1))
```

I have tried:

```
models <- 
  df %>%
  group_by(lag) %>%
  do(model = lm(psit ~ var,data = .))


rsqrd<- 
  model %>%
  do(data.frame(
   lag = .$lag,
    summary(.)$r.squared, summary(.)$fstatistic,summary(.)$pvalue))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the broom library's `glance` function to get the summary statistics you want from a series of linear models:

```
library(broom)
rsqrd <- 
    models %>%
    ungroup() %>% group_by(lag) %>%
    do(glance(.$model[[1]]))
```

`glance` takes a single linear model and returns a one-row data frame of summary statistics.